# SQL query to execute faster - no relationship among tables - generate result quicker

Tags: mysql, sql, database, performance

I have 4 individual tables like below and each of the table have same no of 5 columns ( ID, Shape1, Shape2, Shape3, Shape4). All 4 tables have no relationship between them. Cannot think of any possible relationship.

[Table Design](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xFzfr.png)

Each table have 100 Million rows of data, 100 X 4 = 400 Million

If I run the below query

```
SELECT id 
FROM Table1
WHERE 'Shape1' = 400 AND Shape 'Shape2' = 300 AND 'Shape3' = 500 AND 'Shape4' = 200
```

It searches each table in 1.232 Secs. This is where the bottleneck comes, I have to wait 9.032 second to all four queries to complete when run individually.

I also tried UNION like below but it was really slow 17.042 Secs
[UNION](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a1mKW.png)

Not sure about Joining table here, as nothing can be joined together. I know

**My question:- Can you search all these tables together ? Combine in a single query Or individual execution of query is the only way for faster execution.**

Machine DB :- win 7 X64 - 64 GB RAM COREi7 SSD disk.

DB info :- Memory table for testing to achieve 1.232 Secs per table - Select statement

DB production :- MyISAM table achieves 2.808 secs per table - Select statement

Comment: Please provide the results of `EXPLAIN SELECT id 
FROM Table1
WHERE 'Shape1' = 400 AND Shape 'Shape2' = 300 AND 'Shape3' = 500 AND 'Shape4' = 200` and the `UNION` query. As stated in the answer by Gordon Linoff, indexing the columns as a group would speed up the query containing the criteria for each of the columns.

Comment: one option you don't mention -- combine the tables into one table... then you just have a single table!!

Comment: @Hogan If I combine the tables together, it would become really slow (because of Size) and second thing it would be harder to tell in which region the shapes were ordered

Comment: @fyrye here you go [link](https://i.imgsafe.org/507e94ffa0.png)

Comment: @AdamHochker I've a table here that has over 2 billion rows in it and is not slow, size has nothing to do with speed if you design it correctly

Comment: @Hogan I have acquired this DB at work and have been asked to fix the slow running queries from this Database server.                                       Just for info - How much time does it takes for you to Search 2 billion rows   and what size of DB you hold.

Comment: @AdamHochker Yea, creating the appropriate indexes will dramatically speed up the queries on the tables, be sure to index all of the tables. You could also segregate the data in a single table by adding an additional column for example `category` and be able to determine where the dataset was assigned. Example: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/40ebb This would reduce disk reads and writes since the data would not be spanned elsewhere. It also depends on how the mysql server is configured as well as the storage engine assigned to the table(s).

Comment: Keep in mind, it may take a while for the table to become indexed. You can also run an optimization on the table(s).  `OPTIMIZE TABLE \`Table1\`;` See: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/optimize-table.html in order to sort the indexes to speed up queries even more.

Comment: @AdamHochker - searches against indexed columns come back in seconds.  However this is DB2 not mysql -- not sure other DB systems could perform as well.  In any case, make some indexes and your problem will be solved.

Comment: @fyrye thanks a lot, indexes made a big difference, now its returning the results in 0 secs

Answer (score 3):

This query:

```
SELECT id 
FROM Table1
WHERE 'Shape1' = 400 AND Shape 'Shape2' = 300 AND 'Shape3' = 500 AND 'Shape4' = 200
```

Probably does not do what you expect.  It should return no rows because you are comparing strings to integers.

Write this as:

```
SELECT id 
FROM Table1
WHERE Shape1 = 400 AND Shape2 = 300 AND Shape3 = 500 AND Shape4 = 200
```

All the comparisons are equality comparisons.  So, try this index:

```
CREATE INDEX idx_table1_5 ON table1(Shape1, Shape2, Shape3, Shape4, id);
```

This should speed the first query.  You can create similar indexes for the other tables.

Note:  The order of the first four columns doesn't matter.  But `id` should be the last.

Comment: You can also replace the `'` (single quotes) with a `\`` (backtick)  eg: `\`Shape1\``

Comment: @fyrye . . . There is no need escape the names, so backticks are not needed.

Comment: it is best practice to always escape, despite it not being needed. Though my comment was to provide context as to why the backticks were misinterpreted as single quotes by the OP.

Comment: @GordonLinoff The query which I posted does return results correctly Those ticks are by defaults in phpymyadmin query builder and I think it covers the column names in bacticks by default. its not searching for string because the integer are not quoted in ticks

Comment: @GordonLinoff can we join all the tables together and search in one query because they have same column names. is that possible ?

Comment: @AdamHochker You can do that with UNION ALL but that won't make it faster, an index will.

Comment: thanks everyone will create index to see to effect, will share my findings

Comment: @GordonLinoff Your index hint made a big difference, the queries are returning  in Showing rows 0 - 0 (1 total, Query took 0.0000 seconds.) thanks a lot for your help

Comment: @AdamHochker . . . I would say that is faster.  A lot faster.